# Null Table adapter value with if then statement

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, sql-server-2005, dataset

I have a VB.Net program that checks to see if a specific terminal has been used over the last week.  I'd like to use an if then statement to send me the results.  IF the tableadapter is Empty (NULL) then I would like it to execute something in the program...  Right now I have:

```
Me.1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.SwiperCheck.1, DTstartdate, TodayEnd)

If (Me.SwiperCheck.1.Count = 0) Then

msgbox ("It Worked")
```

Here is my dataset query:

```
SELECT        CASE WHEN COUNT(sTerminal) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE COUNT(sTerminal) END AS terminal
FROM            Swipe
WHERE        (dtCreated BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) AND (sTerminal = 'Swiper 1')
```

However it's not working and I know the output is "Null"  If the output is NOT null, the program works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to return no records when the count is zero then you have to do something like this:

```
SELECT        COUNT(sTerminal) terminal
FROM            Swipe
WHERE        (dtCreated BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) AND (sTerminal = 'Swiper 1')
HAVING COUNT(sTerminal) > 0
```

That should make your orignial IF work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the 0 to dbnull or

```
me.swipercheck.1.count is nothing
```

Comment: "Is" operator does not accept operands of the 'Integer'.  Operands must be referenced or nullable types.  I have tried DBnull as well and dbnull returns the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your query, as written, will always have one row. Your condition is checking the row count on the table. So "If (1=0) Then" ....

What you really need to check is:

```
If (Me.SwiperCheck.1.Item(0) Is DBNull.Value) Then
```

Comment: @Shmewnix Did you try to debug your code? Set a break-point on the `if` statement and put `Me.SwiperCheck.1.Item(0)` in the Watch window. See what's inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the NULL return from your query is giving you trouble.  You can simplify your query by removing the CASE Statement and returning Count(sTerminal).   Then you have a consistent return value:

```
SELECT    COUNT(sTerminal) AS terminal
FROM            Swipe
WHERE        (dtCreated BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) AND (sTerminal = 'Swiper 1')
```

Then I would follow @Bill's suggestion since you always have one row returned:

```
If (Me.SwiperCheck.1.Item(0) = 0 ) Then
```

See this article about your 'nullable' error [MSDN-Nullable Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235245.aspx)

Comment: Error 1 Operator '=' is not defined for types Swipercheck.1Row' and 'Integer'

Comment: @Shmewnix...hard to know what the cause of that is without seeing the code for the class.  But, this idea is, you have a returned value from the query that can be found and logic applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

Tried IsDbNull(me.swipercheck.1.count) = false instead? (Sorry I don't seem to be able to write the little comments on posts yet due to rep).